# Broker may not be available in connecting kafka connector with kafka broker in docker compose

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect

I am using docker container to build zookeeper, kafka and connect.

```
version: '2.1'
services:


  zookeeper:
    image: debezium/zookeeper
    ports:
     - 2181:2181
     - 2888:2888
     - 3888:3888
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka-multibinder-1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9094:9094"

    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=127.0.0.1
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181

      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INSIDE://:9094,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=INSIDE://:9094,OUTSIDE://:9092
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INSIDE

    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  kafka-connect:
    image: debezium/connect
    hostname: kafka-connect
    ports:
     - 8083:8083
    depends_on:
     - kafka
    environment:
     BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
     GROUP_ID: 1
     CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_configs
     OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_offsets
```

however the logs warms me that 'could not be established. Broker may not be available'

```
kafka-connect_1  | 2020-10-18 04:11:44,671 INFO   ||  Kafka version: 2.5.0   [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser]
kafka-connect_1  | 2020-10-18 04:11:44,672 INFO   ||  Kafka commitId: 66563e712b0b9f84   [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser]
kafka-connect_1  | 2020-10-18 04:11:44,674 INFO   ||  Kafka startTimeMs: 1602994304669   [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser]
kafka-connect_1  | 2020-10-18 04:11:44,806 WARN   ||  [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.   [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient]
kafka-connect_1  | 2020-10-18 04:11:44,918 WARN   ||  [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.   [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient]
kafka-connect_1  | 2020-10-18 04:11:45,024 WARN   ||  [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.   [org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient]
kafka-connect_1  | 2020-10-18 04:12:44,713 INFO   ||  [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed   [org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager]
kafka-connect_1  | org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=fetchMetadata, deadlineMs=1602994364719) timed out at 9223372036854775807 after 1 attempt(s)
kafka-connect_1  | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: The AdminClient thread has exited.
kafka-connect_1  | 2020-10-18 04:12:44,722 ERROR  ||  Stopping due to error   [org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed]
kafka-connect_1  | org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties.
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:64)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:45)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:95)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
kafka-connect_1  | Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listNodes, deadlineMs=1602994364707) timed out at 1602994364708 after 1 attempt(s)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConnectUtils.lookupKafkaClusterId(ConnectUtils.java:58)
kafka-connect_1  |  ... 3 more
kafka-connect_1  | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=listNodes, deadlineMs=1602994364707) timed out at 1602994364708 after 1 attempt(s)
kafka-connect_1  | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
```

Comment: Is broker available from the host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Kafka configuration port `9094` is used for inter broker communication. But in Kafka connect you trying to connect to the broker via port `9092`.

As you are trying to connect to port `9092` then `localhost:9092` will be sent as metadata to the Kafka connect for further communication but `localhost:9092` is not available inside the docker network. Use below Kafka connect configuration to connect -

```
kafka-connect:
    image: debezium/connect
    hostname: kafka-connect
    ports:
     - 8083:8083
    depends_on:
     - kafka
    environment:
     BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9094
     GROUP_ID: 1
     CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_configs
     OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_offsets
```

The concept of Advertised listeners is a little bit trickiest. Refer to this [link](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/) if you want to know more about listeners and advertised listeners.

Comment: easily missed, this did solve my issue, Thank you  @Ravi

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while trying to set up Kafka through a docker compose file and after spending few research hours i solved it like this:

on the Kafka service at docker file, i defined a configuration field called       **KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME**, with this config we define the address/IP that clients (producers and consumers) should use in order to connect with the Kafka brokers, so i configured it like this:

```
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
```

and then when i started again the docker compose file the clients were able to connect to the broker, you can see the Kafka logs that says the message highlighted on the screenshot below:
[image]

After that i configured in my spring boot application, on the application.propertied file, i defined the field:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
```